# Is it possible to only read first Json Array Element from a stream with Json.net?

Tags: json, json.net

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(await blob.OpenReadAsync()))
using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(sr))
{
    var axyz = JToken.ReadFrom(jsonTextReader); 
    if(axyz.Type != JTokenType.Array)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there a way to just read the first element of the array with json.net. The json file is really large and i only need the first element.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage JSON#, which is designed specifically to extract embedded JSON objects from within large JSON files using something like this:

```
const string jsonText= @"{ "someObject": {...";
var jsonParser = new JsonObjectParser();

using (var stream = 
    new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonText))) {
    Json.Parse(_jsonParser, stream, "myFirstObject");
}
```

Check out [this post](http://insidethecpu.com/2014/10/22/ultrafast-json-parsing/) and the follow up tutorial series for more info.